# JOIN tables names returned from SELECT

Tags: mysql

I want to JOIN 5-20 tables (could change) on order_id in an updateable view to dump from a production mysql database into a stage mysql database. I have a query that returns all tables with a column name of 'order_id':

> SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'order_id'

Lets pretend the above is 'target_tables' and the following is valid syntax

> SELECT * FROM target_tables 
>   JOIN target_tables
>    ON order_id WHERE
>   order_id > 20787

What would the correct syntax be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this solution with NATURAL JOIN and prepared statement. It may not work as intended if some tables have columns with the same name and you don't want to join on them. You can add the keyword LEFT between NATURAL and JOIN to use LEFT JOIN in place of INNER JOIN.

```
SET @my_query := CONCAT(
    'SELECT * FROM ', (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME SEPARATOR ' NATURAL JOIN ')
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'order_id'
    ), ' WHERE order_id > 20787'
);
PREPARE stmt FROM @my_query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Don't forget to modify 'your_schema' to your database name.